# What is meant by "it has Tooling Support"?

Tags: maui

I tried to follow Microsoft guidelines for Windows Applications.   I will write apps using .NET MAUI.

Straight off the bat I noticed this `.xaml` file in the Quick Start MAUI project I created in VS2022. Personally I hadn't encountered these before, so I went to read about them.

At the Learn.Microsoft website it states this:

```
XAML allows developers to define user interfaces in .NET Multi-platform App UI 
(.NET MAUI) apps using markup rather than code. XAML is not required in 
a .NET MAUI app, but it is the recommended approach to developing your UI because 
it's often more succinct, more visually coherent, and has tooling support
```

What does it mean "and has tooling support" in the context of using XAML, as opposed to just purely C#?

Comment: First hit when I Google "tooling support for XAML": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/?view=vs-2022 :(

Comment: Does c# not have "tooling support" then?

Comment: I assume it means that VS has built in support for working with XAML files - Intellisense, formatting tools. etc

Comment: I mean it says "it is not required in MAUI project, but IS RECOMMENDED because... it has tooling support" ? I am trying to figure out what exactly they mean by this. C# has tools/libraries that can be used also

Comment: I agree that "has tooling support" is neither clear nor helpful. The one benefit I see vs c#, re tools, is ["Hot Reload"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin). This can make it faster to tweak UI.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad some people agree :D . Since writing I have gotten used to XAML. Its kinda weird like writing a website but its actually a multi-plat app. Its pretty cool really. I think when I first started out learning C# this is how I had imagined it being then and I was confused at the time that it couldn't be done in this way. Maybe I can see appeal of this for those already family with making websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Steve suggested, with the assistance of `XAML Hot Reload`, it can enable you to view the result of `XAML changes` in your running app, without having to rebuild your project. Without XAML Hot Reload, you have to build and deploy your app every time you want to view the result of a XAML change or in `C# code`(purely C#).

Also, XAML has several `advantages` over `C# code`(purely C#):

- XAML is often more **succinct** and **readable** than equivalent code.
- The parent-child hierarchy inherent in XML allows XAML to mimic with
  greater visual clarity **the parent-child hierarchy** of user-interface
  objects.